# How to select an option with multiple duplicate selects without updating all the selects?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have multiple select tags that use ng-options in each. They all display from the same array of items. However, when I select one item, all the select gets updated to that item. Is there a way to prevent this?

```
<select ng-model="selectedClass" ng-options="className as className for className in classes track">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Class</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="selectedClass" ng-options="className as className for className in classes track">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Class</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="selectedClass" ng-options="className as className for className in classes track">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Class</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the `select`s are getting updated because they all reference the same `ng-model`.

If each `select` should be independent, they must use different models:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.classes = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <!--selectedClass1-->
  <select ng-model="selectedClass1" ng-options="className as className for className in classes">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Class</option>
  </select>

  <!--selectedClass2-->
  <select ng-model="selectedClass2" ng-options="className as className for className in classes">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Class</option>
  </select>

  <!--selectedClass3-->
  <select ng-model="selectedClass3" ng-options="className as className for className in classes">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Class</option>
  </select>
  
  <div>selectedClass1: {{selectedClass1}}</div>
  <div>selectedClass2: {{selectedClass2}}</div>
  <div>selectedClass3: {{selectedClass3}}</div>
</div>
```

If you're using a directive, you can pass the model into the directive's isolate scope:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', MyCtrl])
  .directive('mySelect', mySelect)

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.selections = [];

  $scope.classes = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

  $scope.addSelect = function() {
    $scope.selections.push({
      selectedClass: null
    });
  };

  $scope.removeSelect = function(index) {
    $scope.selections.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

function mySelect() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      selection: '=',
      classes: '='
    },
    template: '<select' +
      ' ng-model="selection.selectedClass"' +
      ' ng-options="className as className for className in classes">' +
      '<option value="" disabled selected>Select Class</option>' +
      '</select>'
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="selection in selections">
    <my-select selection="selection" classes="classes"></my-select>
    <button ng-click="removeSelect($index)">Remove</button>
  </div>

  <button ng-click="addSelect()">Add a select</button>

  <div>selections: {{selections}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had a feeling this was the case. I create these select blocks from a directive template when I click a button. I'm not sure how to change the ng-model to increment. What should I do here?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include dynamically adding directives at the click of a button.

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect!

Comment: How would I use the selection as a key for another variable? I have an attribute map called attributes. I tried <div>{{attributes.selection}}</div> but it doesn't show anything.